# Ignore blank cells in a Range for a VBA formula that determines Range Data Type

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to read through hundreds of columns on a worksheet and determine whether the data type is alpha, numerical, or alphanumerical. However, the formula keeps returning "empty" when there are too many empty cells in the column. Any advice on how to best ignore the empty cells in the range?

Below is the code

```
Function DataType(aVal As Variant) As String

Select Case TypeName(aVal)
    Case "String"
        If IsNumeric(aVal) Then
            If LCase(aVal) Like "*d*" Then
                DataType = "Alphanumeric"
            Else
                DataType = "numerical"
            End If
        Else
            If aVal Like "*[0-9]*" Then
                DataType = "Alphanumeric"
            Else
                If aVal = vbNullString Then
                    DataType = "null"
                Else
                    DataType = "Alpha"
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Case "Boolean"
        DataType = LCase(TypeName(aVal))

    Case "Double", "Single", "Integer", "Long", "Byte"
        DataType = "Numerical"

    Case "Range"
        DataType = DataType(aVal.Cells(1, 1).Value)

    Case Else
        DataType = LCase(TypeName(aVal))

End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Are you asking for a comparison operator if a cell is empty? If so, use `IsEmpty`

Answer (score 0):

Check if your cell contains something first. You can use this code:

```
Function DataType(aVal As Variant) As String
    If aVal <> "" Then
        'Put the rest of your function code here
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
Case Else
    If Not IsEmpty(aVal) Then
        DataType = LCase(TypeName(aVal))
    End If
```

Alternately you could check to see if the cell intersects with `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` in the calling code.

Comment: This seems to make the function return a blank cell rather than the data type of the data within the range

Comment: @mfort - That's precisely the point, isn't it?  The reason that you're getting "empty" is that a blank cell returns a `.Value` containing a `Variant` of type `vbEmpty`.  So `TypeName()` returns "Empty".  What do you *want* it show?

Comment: So, I want it to ignore the blanks in the column, and return the data type of the data that is in the column (alpha, numerical, alphanumerical) like in other columns that have more data and less blanks

Comment: @mfort - Can you edit your post to include the calling function then?  The one in your question only gets the description of whatever `aVal` is.